# Parameters in bash $PS1 variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, working-directory

Between the various parameters that can be included in the `bash` `PS1` variable, `\w` expands

> the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
>   (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)

as stated in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

My `$HOME` is set to `/home/myuser/` (the same value specified in `/etc/passwd`), but the expansion of `\w` in `PS1` gives `/home/myuser` when I am in the `$HOME` directory. So, it is not «abbreviated with a tilde».

I am Using Ubuntu 16.04 with `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

What's wrong? What is the source from where `\w` actually copies the path of the current directory?

Comment: Do `cd` once to see if that helps. Also, is your home directory set to `/home/myuser/`, with a slash at the end, in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: @Kusalananda `cd` didn't have effect. As I wrote in the question, my home directory was `/home/myuser/` with a slash in the end, also in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trailing `/` in `/home/myuser/` is confusing bash.  I think you'll see normal behavior if you remove it.

That slash isn't part of the directory name; it's a path separator.  It shouldn't be in `/etc/passwd`, and it shouldn't be in `$HOME`.

You can test that theory without touching a file using just:

```
HOME=/home/myuser
```

after which the tilde should appear in your prompt.